# PHP Get Array String Pointing to Another Array Object

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I've got an array which points to a bunch of other arrays, structured like a JSON object. This is the structure of it:

```
$allRows= array(
    "Global task 1"=> array(
        "major-task"=> array(
            "points"=> 850,
        ),
        "minor-task"=> array(
            array(
                "points"=> 400,
                "task"=> "Minor task 1",
            ),
            array(
                "points"=> 200,
                "task"=> "Minor task 2",
            ),
            array(
                "points"=> 250,
                "task"=> "Minor task 3",
            ),
        )
    ),
    "Global task 2"=> array(
        "major-task"=> array(
            "points"=> 850,
        ),
        "minor-task"=> array(
            array(
                "points"=> 400,
                "task"=> "Minor task 1",
            ),
            array(
                "points"=> 200,
                "task"=> "Minor task 2",
            ),
            array(
                "points"=> 250,
                "task"=> "Minor task 3",
            ),
        )
    ),
);
```

I'm trying to be able to access each of these in the following way:

```
foreach ($allRows as $row) {
    // Print Global task 1, Global task 2, etc
    echo $row[0]; // unsure how to acquire this 'Global task x' text

    // I've already accessed this just fine
    echo $row["major-task"]["points"];
}
```

I've got the latter `echo` just fine, but **I'm unable to print** the `Global task 1` and `Global task 2`. Any help printing this text would be highly appreciated!

Comment: get both the keys and values on your foreach loop like so `foreach ($allRows as $taskName => $row){ // result here !  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tasks are the keys for `$allRows`, you'll need to catch them in the foreach:

```
foreach ($allRows as $taskName => $row) {
    echo $taskName; // "Global task 1"

    echo $row["major-task"]["points"];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I originally tried this but kept trying to `echo $row;` instead of the taskName. Will accept this when it lets me!

Answer (score 1):

Use it like this:

```
foreach ($allRows as $key => $row) {
    // Print Global task 1, Global task 2, etc
    echo $key;

    // I've already accessed this just fine
    echo $row["major-task"]["points"];
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is get the `key` for the `multidimensional array`

To do this, define the a `$key variable` with the `foreach() loop`

Example:

```
foreach ($allRows as $key => $value) {
    echo $key; // Global task 1 or Global task 2
    echo $value["major-task"]["points"];
}
```

Also, **does not matter**, but when using strings in arrays, I like to use ''. Example:

```
echo $value['major-task']['points'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use recursive function to parse multidimensional array and get values, here are reference links to understand better:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php

[Iterate multidimensional Array recursively and return same array structure and inserting new key/values in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394497/iterate-multidimensional-array-recursively-and-return-same-array-structure-and-i)

And here is solution with your current implementation:

```
foreach ($allRows as $key=>$row) {
    // Print Global task 1, Global task 2, etc
    //echo $row[0]; // unsure how to acquire this 'Global task x' text
    echo $key;
    // I've already accessed this just fine
    echo $row["major-task"]["points"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an associative array, if you want to access it with indexes you need to get the array of its keys `array_keys($row)` first:

```
 foreach ($allRows as $row) {
    $keys = array_keys($row);
    print_r($row[$keys[0]]);
}
```